# Mongoose deleting documents through array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Post model and there is array of comments inside him (objectsId that refer to the Comment model).
When I am deleting a post i want to delete his comments too
I was trying to use forEach and its worked :

```
post.comments.forEach(async (comment) => {
  await comment.remove({ session: postDeletingSession });
});
```

I am sure that there is a better way to do that, can somone help me to find one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `post.comments` is an array of ObjectIDs, you can use [`Model.deleteMany()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-deleteMany) as shown below:

```
await comment.deleteMany({ _id: {  $in: post.comments } })
```